# Show date but not time on Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, date

I have disabled the clock in the Windows 10 taskbar, but this also disables the date and the "calendar button" that comes with it . I would like to have only the date there. Is there a way of achieving this, with or without third party software?

Answer (score 1):

Date and time are part of the clock by design. So natively in Windows 10, you need to enable the clock to see date and time.

You can show time without date, but I do not think date without time.

If you want just time, you need 3rd party software or like to do that.

Windows 11 shows both by default.

That is the best way to go and is the commonly used setting.

Answer (score 0):

Some further googling lead me to https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/releases, which seems to work to customise the clock and date freely as of 2021-09-03. Note that the clock needs to be *enabled* to be able to customise it.

Comment: That is third party software as I noted in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

For "How to Show Only the Time in Windows 10 Taskbar", please enable "Use small taskbar buttons" on Taskbar Settings.

https://www.faqforge.com/windows/how-to-show-only-the-time-in-windows-10-taskbar/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1235166)

Comment: I want to show only the date, not the time.